# Как сделать, чтоб страница на Github Pages запускалась не с корня?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, github-pages

Существует определённый проект xxx (игрушка на JS, с node + webpack).
Все файлы этого проекта хранятся по пути src. В корне лежит непосредственно эта папка и конфигурационные файлы.
Вопрос(-ы) заключается в следующем: как сделать, чтобы сайт запускался на Github Pages не с корня что ли и возможно ли это вовсе?
Github Pages хранит всё же статические сайты, сможет ли он работать с NodeJS?

Comment: Есть предположение, что я могу закидывать на gh-pages папку dist, в которой хранится содержимое сборки.

Comment: Так точно, вы можете в ветку для Github Pages  заливать только папку dist это решит вашу проблему.